# What is the Accumulator in Play Java?

Tags: java, playframework, akka, akka-stream

Now I'm reading the document of Play Java.
And I don't understand these sentences which explain what is the exactly `apply(RequestHeader header)` in Play.

> The return type of the method is an Accumulator. An accumulator is a thin layer around an Akka Streams Sink. An accumulator asynchronously accumulates streams of elements into a result, it can be run by passing in an Akka Streams Source, this will return a CompletionStage that will be redeemed when the accumulator is complete. It is essentially the same thing as a Sink>, in fact it is nothing more than a wrapper around this type, but the big difference is that Accumulator provides convenient methods such as map, mapFuture, recover etc. for working with the result as if it were a promise, where Sink requires all such operations to be wrapped in a mapMaterializedValue call.

Do this mean that `Accumulator` can be the argument of `Akka Streams Source`?  But when I have checked, I couldn't find the method one of whose parameters is equal to `Accumulator`.  And I couldn't do `CompletionStage` in it. 
What in the world they want to tell?

Answer (score 0):

> Do this mean that Accumulator can be the argument of Akka Streams
>   Source?

No, it just mean that Accumulator is created over a Akka Streams source. It runs and accumulate on that Akka stream source and returns a Future object i.e. CompletionStage once the accumulation is complete.

**Accumulator need Akka Stream source, not vice versa.**

Comment: What is the relation between `Accumulator` and `Akka Stream Sink` like?    In addition, is `CompletionStage`  redeemed into `Future` object after completion?